# What is a "common JavaScript library", and how do put code into mine?

Tags: javascript, hierarchy, libraries, directory-structure

Is it just my /javascript directory?  I'm only guessing.  I've had trouble uncovering the answer with google, actually.  Looking into the context of the code I'm trying to apply, though, this seems to be the case.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder, Man, I wish JMax would stop residing on this site.  It's like all he does is close questions.  God forbid he should answer one.  A prior question of mine referred me to a link where it is mentioned.  Face check my other comment, after Tobai's answer, for a link, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Common JavaScript library* just means that you can use this generic snippet of code with the framework of your choice, e.g. jQuery , MooTools, Dojo,….

But those frameworks probably offer this functionality already or it's very easy to replicate. See for example [jQuery clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).

*Not the right answer:* Do you mean the [CommonJS](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1) specification? It describes a module format for JavaScript. For example Node.js uses CommonJS [modules](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules).

Comment: I don't know if that's what I am looking for, Tobai.  You can see where it is used, just after the first code snippet, here: http://www.elliotswan.com/2006/04/12/move-and-copy/

Comment: Ah okay. Well… it just means that you can use this snippet with the library of your choice. Well. I guess the functionality of this thing can be easily replicated with jQuery or any other modern JS Framework.

Comment: @tobai, Does that mean that the code won't work without a JavaScript Framework, such as jQuery, and that I need to inject the code directly into the Framework?  To be honest, I'm having trouble implementing the code.  I tried simply copying and pasting the smaller JS file from the example, and it isn't working on my page.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a directory, it's JavaScript. It just means a common place for *your* JavaScript code, it can go anywhere (that's accessible from the browser).